# Slide in the UIView from Right of screen to left

Tags: ios, uiview, swift4

I am working on app, in which I am showing UITableView. On top of UITableView there is a button filter. Now on that button click, I want to animate the UIVIEW to animate from Right side of screen to left side of screen. And it must animate until it reaches to the 70 percent width of the screen.

Now doing this it will make Previous view a little darker, I want to make a look and feel same like a Navigation drawer in android. but this will only show the Filters settings in that UIView.

I searched out and there is too many library out there to perform the task I wanted, but I want to write the code my self and to animate a UIView or a Nib design to do so.

Is there anyway to perform what I wanted without using any library or anything? Please let me know I am waiting. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: initiate your UIView with width zero, then use UIView.animate to set your width accordingly.

Comment: there are some views inside it, should I set their width too?

Answer (score 5):

The way that I like to animate views, in cases like this, is to use a transform on the view – which preserves the view's layout and appearance, and generally will look better than changing the width of the view.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: {

   let moveLeft = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -(view.bounds.width * 0.7), y: 0.0)
    viewController.view.transform = moveLeft

})
```

To return the view to its normal position, simply set the transform again, using 0.0 as the `translationX` value.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: {

   let zero = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    viewController.view.transform = zero

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily perform the animation if you're using Auto Layout by playing with the view's constraints. You could constrain the view's trailing anchor to the view's leading anchor (the view will be off the screen), add a reference to the constraint in code (by adding an IBOutlet) and play with its constant when you want to show it or hide it (for example, you could set the constant to be equal to the width of the view you wan to show).

> Now doing this it will make Previous view a little darker, I want to make a look and feel same like a Navigation drawer in android. but this will only show the Filters settings in that UIView.

To achieve this effect, you could add a black view on top of the table view and adjust its alpha value. When the Slide In UIView is hidden, you can hide it, and when it is shown, you can show it.

Answer (score 0):

Move UIView right to left

```
 var rightFrame = yourView.frame
    rightFrame.origin.x = 300 // initial frame right
    var finalFrame = yourView.frame
    finalFrame.origin.x = 0 // final frame to left
    yourView.frame = rightFrame
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: { [self] in
       
        yourView.frame = finalFrame
    }) { finished in
        
    }
```